# Counting the restaurants with a specific rating mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

I have a table of tripadvisor data. There are columns (restaurant, rank, score, user_name,review_stars,review_date,user_reviews....) and other columns that are not useful for my question...

I am trying to return each restaurant with how many 3-star reviews they have and list them using the rank column from high to low.

I know i can use count, i was thinking of count if ( review_stars=3) and then order by rank to return it... i am stuck and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  `where review_stars = 3`.

Comment: Try studying the SQL clauses. It will help you a lot in programming languages, and on your future projects to be developed. This site will help you to understand what was you are looking for. [https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/index.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to accomplish is counting **how many** 3 star reviews **each restaurant** has ..

You really are almost there --  Your original question really does contains all the answers, just written out in long-hand.  Think about what you are asking:

"I need to `SELECT` the `restaurants` that `have 3 star reviews` and `count` how many there are *per restaurant*"  --  The basic syntax you are missing is `GROUP BY` --  Which groups all of your results **per restaurant** to a single row.

```
SELECT restaurant, count(*) as 3_star_count from table where review_stars = '3' GROUP BY restaurant
```

This is a basic example.  But from what you are asking .. This syntax should get you the number of 3 star reviews for each restaurant.

I would recommend that you look into `SQL` clauses and what they mean as @Alexis stated in an earlier comment.  The `WHERE` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause (especially this one) are what you want to understand here.

Comment: Small note - this syntax will get the the number of three star reviews only as long as the restaurant has at least one. Any restaurant with no reviews or no three star reviews will not show up. If you want to see them as well, you need one query that returns all the reviews, with a left join to one that has the number of three star reviews (or a sub query in the select)